# Input defaults to BATS: instead on NYSE:

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine script and I used the below  inputs, but the default value is always setting to "BATS:IBM". How to set value to "NYSE:IBM" instead of "BATS:IBM"?

```
sym = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval="NYSE:IBM")
sym = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval="IBM")
sym = input("NYSE:IBM", type=input.symbol)
```

Answer (score 1):

BATS is Cboe BZX, the free source for the NASDAQ/NYSE data. If your account has no subscription to NYSE, it will automatically redirect you to equivalent Cboe BZX symbol, in this case, BATS:IBM. If you [purchase the NYSE subscription](https://www.tradingview.com/gopro/#markets), it will no longer redirect you and you'll get the proper NYSE:IBM data.